# How to iterate through ul elements within a div and hide them individually on a submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, node.js, express

In my node app using express I have a view function that creates a list of inactive companies, each company has two submit input types "Active" and "Delete". I would like to be able to hit submit and have that individual ul become hidden. However, I'm not quite sure how to iterate over  individually. Every time I've tried I end up hiding all the elements. Here's my view function:

```
function inactiveFiltered(companyObject) {
    return `
        <ul class="companyinfo">
            <li class="list-info">${companyObject.company_type}</li>
            <li class="list-info">${companyObject.company_name}</li>
            <li class="list-info">${companyObject.company_location}</li>
            <li class="list-info">${companyObject.company_phone}</li>
            <br>
            <li class="list-buttons">
                <form action="/activeList" method="POST" class="myform">
                    <input type="hidden" name="companyId" value="${companyObject.id}">
                    <input type="submit" value="Active">
                </form>
                <form action="/deletecompany" method="POST">
                    <input type="hidden" name="companyId" value="${companyObject.id}">
                    <input type="submit" value="Delete">
                </form>
            </li>
            <br>
        </ul>
    `
}

function inactiveList(arrayOfCompanies){
    const companyItems = arrayOfCompanies.map(inactiveFiltered).join('');

    return `
        <div class="list inactive-list">
            ${companyItems}
        </div>
    `
}

module.exports = inactiveList;
```

One function takes an array of companies and then creates an company object. Now here's the latest JQuery attempt, but like I said it hides all the ul elements:

```
                $(document.body).submit(function() {
                    $('.companyinfo').each(function(i) {
                        $(this).hide();
                    })
                })
```

I've been stuck on this for waaay too long and would love any help whatsoever. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are hiding all elements at the same time because the selector `.companyinfo` returns a list of all elements using the class `companyinfo` which are all companies in your case. That's why they get hidden all at the same time

One way to achieve your goal is to add ids to the `ul` elements to be able to address them for each company individually like so: `<ul id="companyinfo_${companyObject.company_name}" class="companyinfo">`.

Then add a method `hideCompany()` to replace the `$(document.body).submit(function()` part:

```
function hideCompany(companyname) {
    $('#companyinfo_' + companyname).hide();
}
```

Finally, modify `<input type="submit" value="Delete">`to read `<input type="submit" value="Delete" onclick="hideCompany('${companyObject.company_name}')">`.

Comment: THANKS! Works great.